# How to prevent redrawing the whole infinite scrolling List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI to create an infinite scrolling `List` by:

```swift
// My data structure
struct MyData {
    title: String
}

// My datasource variable
@State var datasource: [MyData]

// My List view
List(datasource.enumerated().map({ $0 }), id: \.title) { (index, myData) in
    MyListRow(myData)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            if index == datasource.count - 2 {
                fetchMoreData()
            }
        })
}
```

By this code, when I scroll to the bottom, the List automatically increases as I wish.

However, in fact, the WHOLE List was redrawn! Which means the List rows that has been previously constructed were de-inited and inited again.

My question is: How to prevent SwiftUI from redrawing the whole list, but only draw the newly added rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inited is not drawn. By modifying datasource you initiated List refresh, which resulted in reconstructing row values, but redrawn (called body) only for those which differ from previous. Moreover List caches rows and does not keep more than fit onto screen, plus couple, at all. So it just cannot redraw whole bunch of rows, because ignores invisibles.

So, just don't do anything heavy in View.init, which I assume you do and complain on it's re-doing on refresh.

Comment: So when the datasource refreshes, all rows structs of my list are re-inited. Does this leads to frequently freeing-and-allocating of memory? Should I just ignore it?

Comment: @Evian, it is re-initing about dozen of rows and swiftui view itself takes usually 16 bytes, so if you don't allocate explicitly something huge in your rows init, then yes, it can definitely be ignored.